# Disable networking driver/modules when booting from live USB

Tags: drivers, grub2, kernel

I want to disable all networking related drivers and modules before I boot off a live Ubuntu USB in try mode. This includes Ethernet, WiFi, and Bluetooth.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Short answer: It can't.

Answer (score 3):

To disable networking drivers and modules before booting into live Ubuntu, you can use the "nomodprobe" and "blacklist" options when starting the live USB. The nomodprobe option prevents any kernel modules from being loaded, while the blacklist option allows you to specify specific drivers or modules that you want to prevent from loading.

Here is an example of how you can use these options when booting from a live USB:

1. Plug in your live Ubuntu USB and restart your computer.
2. When the boot menu appears, press the "e" key to edit the boot options.
3. Use the arrow keys to navigate to the line that starts with "linux" and add the "nomodprobe" and "blacklist" options to the end of this line, like this:

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper nomodprobe blacklist=<DRIVER1>,<DRIVER2>,<MODULE1>,<MODULE2>
```

4. Replace `<DRIVER1>`, `<DRIVER2>`, `<MODULE1>`, and `<MODULE2>` with the names of the drivers and modules that you want to disable. For example, if you want to disable the Ethernet, WiFi, and Bluetooth drivers, you can use the following:

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper nomodprobe blacklist=ethernet,wifi,bluetooth
```

5. Press the "Ctrl + X" keys to boot the live USB with the modified options. This will prevent the specified drivers and modules from being loaded, disabling networking on the live Ubuntu system.

Please note that the above instructions are just an example and may vary depending on your specific system and configuration. If you are not familiar with modifying boot options or are unsure about how to proceed, it is recommended to seek assistance from a more experienced user or a professional. Modifying boot options can have unintended consequences if not done properly, so proceed with caution.

Comment: This answer is WRONG and potentially harmful, as I was not able to shutdown normally and had to resort to cutting power. Unfortunately, I can't downvote or undo my upvote.